# What does this icon mean?

Tags: league-of-legends

I noticed this icon (the snowflake in a rounded triangle) while watching someone stream, but haven't noticed it while playing myself (could just be a lack of paying attention to the screen while not in champ select/game). I haven't seen it before, what does it does it mean?
[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That icon means that a feature called "Auto Fill" is enabled for you. When Auto Fill is enabled, you have a chance of being assigned a role (top, bot, mid, jung, or supp) that you did not queue up for. The purpose of this is to help speed up queue times when there are simply not enough people within your MMR bracket playing. The feature was introduced as part of Riot's dynamic queue initiative, in which they tried to speed up matchmaking and make matches more fair for players of all skill levels.

Unless you are at a very high MMR (typically Diamond 1 or above, or less than the top 1% of players), you won't ever see this icon because there will normally be plenty of players. Chances are you're watching a streamer who is high MMR (they are the most informative and entertaining, after all), and that's why they are getting this icon.

Comment: Oh, ok, that makes sense. The guy I watch is in high masters. I have been auto filled before, but it rarely happens. Do you know which patch this icon got put in?

Comment: AFAIK, it was first enabled about 2 months ago, so that would be patch 6.16 I think?

Comment: I think 6.16 is the latest patch FYI, just pushed 4 days ago.  2 months ago, would probably be 6.14?

Comment: @joedragons Sounds right. I'm at work so I can't check the current patch notes or version number, and I don't usually keep track of the specific version (just the changes therein).

Comment: If @MageXy's answer was satisfying, please upvote it to show your appreciation!